# apt install program without modifying file associations

Tags: apt, kubuntu, kde, default-programs, mime-type

Certain programs when I install them seem to believe they can open a large number of filetypes. Xournal is was a particularly extreme example in Kubuntu 16.04. In Kubuntu 20.04 imagemagick `display` wants to open a large number of files from all images to even `.tex` and `.py` files.

While I can modify my default application for a single file type. I can't find a bulk way to remove all associations from a single program. Which means I have to manually change the file association for literally hundreds of file types.

My main way to fix this is to simply uninstall the offending program if it tries to open too many files it clearly has  no right opening. A preferable solution would be to associate the program no file types on install. I can always manually associate the few types I want.

I use kubuntu, I am not sure if this affects any non-apt solutions to this problem.

Comment: May be a KDE issue? For me, installing any program including Xournal will never take over file types that already have a default application assigned to. The program will appear in "Open with...", and can easily be set to be the default if wished. Looks like this is something that Gnome handles quite well.

Comment: Mention the version of your OS.

Comment: What exactly do you do to make you feel that "Certain programs when I install them seem to believe they can open almost every file under the sun."? I've just installed xournal on Kubuntu 18.04. If I open Dolphin and double-click on `~/.bash_aliases` it opens in geany, my default text editor. If I double-click on budgets.ods, it opens in LibreOffice Calc. If I double-click on a pdf file, it opens in okular. If you provide more details, I'll check my VM's of various 20.04 *buntu flavors. Doesn't seem to "be a KDE issue".

Comment: As for imagemagick, Kubuntu 18.04 comes with it installed. Again, I've not noticed any issues with it trying to open files for which I've already set gwenview as the default. And what does "I am not sure if this affects any non-apt solutions to this problem." mean?

Comment: Added more clarity that Xournal was a huge problem in 16.04 to the point where I stopped using it entirely. Perhaps this is better in more recent versions. In Kubuntu 20.04 imagemagick display seems is associated with a wide variety of formats like ".py".

Either way a single program having the wrong associations is an annoyance of that program. What I would like is a bulk way to override a specific program so if any program tries to open too many files I can bulk disable this.

Comment: Simple solution (didn't test) would be to backup /usr/share/applications/default.list somewhere before running apt install, and restore from backup after install is finished. This should undo any changes it made.

Comment: Please explain your "workflow" to show how you **currently** face problems with imagemagick. How exactly does this problem manifest itself?

Comment: I open dolphin. I go to a file. I double click on it and a black imagemagick pane pops up. When I close it I will right click and Open With...Other Application.. set a new default. Occasionally I will open Settings..File Associations. And start going through those and removing imagemagick. But there are thousands of file types and hundreds of them are assigned to IM. It is a long a laborious mouse-based process. Very much the Windows-style solution